# Alter timezone constraint PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I have an attribute in a table like this:

```
created_date timestamp without timezone
```

Now my requirement is to change the created_date field to the **timestamp with timezone** on the production database but I don't know how to alter this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

To change a column type use `ALTER TABLE` command:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE timestamptz;
```

You can change more than 1 column type in one operation by delimiting `ALTER COLUMN` statements with a comma:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
  ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE timestamptz,
  ALTER COLUMN column_name2 TYPE datatype;
```

For more information check [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).