# Presto: Publish a table with timezone altered to the correct zone

Tags: sql, timezone, presto, timezone-offset

I am trying to change the timezone of a timestamp in presto, however, as I convert the type of column back to timestamp, the timezone correction is reverted. I need to convert it to timestamp/bigint/string to be able to store the data in a schema as the schema does not store the column type timestamp-timezone. I have tried

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(to_unixtime(CAST('2012-10-31 01:00' AS timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific') * 1000 AS bigint)/1000);
```

[PostgreSQL => ALTER TABLE without timezone -> with timezone, using select for TZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006575/postgresql-alter-table-without-timezone-with-timezone-using-select-for-tz)

[Alter timezone constraint PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676323/alter-timezone-constraint-postgresql)

[Can you use a column for the timezone parameter of AT TIME ZONE in Presto / Athena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446184/can-you-use-a-column-for-the-timezone-parameter-of-at-time-zone-in-presto-athe)

[How do I convert a string which is actually a date with timezone to a timestamp in Presto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070592/how-do-i-convert-a-string-which-is-actually-a-date-with-timezone-to-a-timestamp)

But have not been able to solve the issue. Is there a way I can store the timezone appended date column in the table without it being reverted?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample input data and expected result? Also, since you're dealing with timestamps (see more info @ https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37), what's your session's time zone?

Comment: You could do it with current date and try i.e. SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(CAST(CURRENT TIME AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific' AS varchar), 1, 23) AS timestamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(CAST((FROM_UNIXTIME(CAST(1578514469000 AS BIGINT)/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'US/Pacific') AS varchar), 1, 23) AS timestamp)